# MongoDB + PHP: Filter on parsed user-input secure?

Tags: php, mongodb, security, user-input

Is this secure or is it vulnerable to exploitation by user input?

```
$ids = explode(",", $_GET['ids']);

$results = $collection->find([
    'arbitraryId' => ['$in' => $ids]
]);
```

Comment: what are you afraid of? it just iterating over a list of ids to find which ones are there. What happens if user introduces some random string/code there instead of id? well, it will not find anything

Comment: Can they input any kind of mongodb commands or JSON to manipulate the query beyond the intended scope?

Comment: they can but it would fail because it would not execute the commands. Try inserting some mongo commands and see if you can hack it

Comment: yes, vulnerable with noSQLinjection, check it "https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_NoSQL_injection", you have to proper escape user input first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big issue with what you are doing is that people could try random ID's and might luckily see a document that that user might not be allowed to see.

So if this is what you fear, then you should add a session flag that holds the user permission and add permissions to your documents.

```
//this would have been set at user login
$perms = $_SESSION['perms'];

//get the right documents
$results = $collection->find([
    '_id' => ['$in' => $ids],
    'perms' => ['$in' => $perms]
]);
```

Otherwise, if an id does not exist, then it would just return an empty array. There is really no injection here as long as we are talking about reading documents by id, unless you convert those IDs back to MongoID at query time. In this case you should at least validate the format of each id before converting to MongoID, using at least this regex

```
 [a-z0-9]{24}
```

Comment: Not too worried about people trying random IDs, just worried about an injection-style, DoS, or similar type of exploitative attack.

Comment: There are none in your case.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case it's not injection-vulnerable per se, but may throw an error:

```
GET /?ids[]=1
```

This input will break your first line of code because PHP treats such params as arrays and would try to run `explode()` against it, which would cause

```
ErrorException: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
```

---

The the common practice is to validate the request first and proceed only on successful validation, otherwise return the `422 unprocessable entity` status. Most frameworks give you convenient tools to easily accomplish this. To illustrate, in Laravel it would look something like this:

```php
$this->validate($request, [
  'ids' => 'string',
]); 
// quits and returns 422 status automatically on validation failure
```

Comment: @Dan added example in the answer. Other than that it's injection-safe